# Angular Event emitter of one component gets confused with another

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

## BACKGROUND

I have two components image-input-single and a test container. image-input-single is a "dumb" component that simplifys the process of selecting an image, getting the compressed file and it's url.

It's Typescript file and HTML file is shown bellow

```js
@Component({
  selector: "app-image-input-single",
  templateUrl: "./image-input-single.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./image-input-single.component.scss"]
})
export class ImageInputSingleComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  image ? : string;

  @Input()
  circular!: boolean;

  @Output()
  imageAdded = new EventEmitter < Image > ();

  @Output()
  imageRemoved = new EventEmitter < Image > ();

  onImageClear = () => {
    console.log("Image clear");
    if (this.image) {
      this.imageRemoved.emit({
        image: this.image
      });
    }
  };

  constructor(
    private ng2ImgMax: Ng2ImgMaxService,
    public sanatizer: DomSanitizer
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.image);
  }
  onFileChanged(event: any) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      const rawImage = event.target.files[0];
      this.ng2ImgMax.compressImage(rawImage, 0.2).subscribe(
        result => {
          const file = new File([result], result.name);
          const reader = new FileReader();
          // @ts-ignore
          reader.onload = (pe: ProgressEvent) => {
            this.imageAdded.emit({
              // @ts-ignore
              image: pe.target.result,
              imageFile: file
            });
          };

          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)" accept="image/*" multiple id="imageInput">
<div [ngClass]="{'boxCircular': circular,
'box': true}">
  <label for="imageInput">

    <mat-icon *ngIf="!image; else imageTemp" class="camIcon">camera_alt</mat-icon>

    <ng-template #imageTemp>
      <button mat-icon-button class="cancelButton" (click)="onImageClear()" type="button">
        <mat-icon class="cancelIcon">cancel</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <img [src]="sanatizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(image)" [ngClass]="{'profilePic': circular, 'book': !circular}">
    </ng-template>
  </label>
</div>
```

I then have a simple component which contains two instances of image-input-single

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Image } from "src/app/models/Image";

@Component({
  selector: "app-test",
  templateUrl: "./test.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./test.component.scss"]
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  image1?: Image;
  image2?: Image;

  imageAdd1 = (image: Image) => {
    console.log("1");
    this.image1 = image;
  };

  imageAdd2 = (image: Image) => {
    console.log("2");
    this.image2 = image;
  };

  imageRemove1 = (image: Image) => {
    this.image1 = image;
  };

  imageRemove2 = (image: Image) => {
    this.image2 = image;
  };

  ngOnInit() {
    this.image2 = {
      image: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwwhZ.png"
    };
  }
}
```

```html
<app-image-input-single (imageAdded)="imageAdd1($event)" (imageRemoved)="imageRemove1($event)" [image]="image1?.image">

</app-image-input-single>
<app-image-input-single (imageAdded)="imageAdd2($event)" (imageRemoved)="imageRemove2($event)" [image]="image2?.image">

</app-image-input-single>
```

## PROBLEM

imageAdd2 or imageRemove2 is never ever triggered even when interacting with the second image input select component. imageAdd1 and imageRemove1 is always triggered when ever adding or removing an image from 1 or 2.

Been dealing with this for days and nothing I've tried has worked, would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: the problem might be in ` this.ng2ImgMax.compressImage`. I am willing to bet that the observable it emits is reused between calls and that leads to the 1st component being triggered when the 2nd image is edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> #### Cause

- `ImageInputSingleComponent` might be sharing the same instance of `Ng2ImgMaxService` which is leading to this problem.
- The second issue is with `id`=`imageInput`. This is hard coded in html however it must be unique for each instance of Component.

> #### Fix

Just provide `Ng2ImgMaxService` to `ImageInputSingleComponent` level to ensure it each component has its own copy.

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-image-input-single",
  templateUrl: "./image-input-single.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./image-input-single.component.scss"],
  providers : [Ng2ImgMaxService] //<-- Ng2ImgMaxService is added in provider list
})
export class ImageInputSingleComponent implements OnInit {

}
```

Comment: Did that, still same issue only imageAdd1 and imageRemove1 is ever triggered.

Comment: Your id `id='imageInput"` must be unique. As of now its hard coded and all instance of Component will have the same is which is second issue.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by id? I dont have any id input prop for the component.

Comment: `id` and `for` in html. `<input type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)" accept="image/*" multiple id="imageInput">`

Comment: Thank you so so much, this bug was killing me.